# How do I execute this Java Code that goes infinite loops?

Tags: java

```
public class Exercise3_10 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int array[][] = new int[4][4]; // array는 4x4의 2차원 배열
    
    int i;
    
    boolean duplicate_index[] = new boolean[16];
    
    for(i=0;i<16;i++) // duplicate_index 배열의 모든 원소에 false를 삽입
    {
        duplicate_index[i] = false;
    }
    
    for(i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        int random_index = (int)Math.random()*15; // 0부터 15까지의 인덱스를 랜덤으로 뽑기
        
        if(!duplicate_index[random_index]) // duplicate_index배열의 랜덤 인덱스의 원소가
        {                                  // false라면 array배열에 랜덤숫자 부여 후 true로 변경
            int random_number = (int)(Math.random()*10+1); // 1부터 10까지 랜덤 정수 뽑기
            
            switch(random_index)
            {
            case 0: case 1: case 2: case 3:
                array[0][random_index] = random_number;
                duplicate_index[random_index] = true; 
                break;
            case 4: case 5: case 6: case 7:
                array[1][random_index - 4] = random_number;
                duplicate_index[random_index] = true; 
                break;
            case 8: case 9: case 10: case 11:
                array[1][random_index - 8] = random_number;
                duplicate_index[random_index] = true; 
                break;
            case 12: case 13: case 14: case 15:
                array[1][random_index - 12] = random_number;
                duplicate_index[random_index] = true; 
                break;
            }
        }
        else // true인 경우 현재 반복문을 한번 더 실행
        {
            i--;
            continue;
        }
            
    }   
    
    for(i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
        {
            System.out.print(array[i][j] + "   ");          
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}

}
```

i want to make a two-dimentional array.
then, i need ten random numbers (range 1~10) in random index.
the rest of indexes are '0'.
i made a following code. but, this code didnt show any output in eclipse.
i think it goes infinite loop. but i dont know whats wrong.
i need your helps!!

Comment: Please put your code comments in English

Comment: There are quite a number issues in your code, but the most glaring one is `(int)Math.random()*15` - this always results in 0, and causes an infinite loop, as you first truncate a floating point number from 0 to 1 with `(int)` to zero, and then multiply it by 15. Use parentheses to ensure that it does what you want: `(int)(Math.random()*15)` (and it should be `*16`, most likely, otherwise you never hit index 15)

Comment: If you do exactly the same thing in all branches of a switch statement, then you should move that statement outside of the switch so that you don't repeat it so many times: `duplicate_index[random_index] = true;`. Then you have a bug: you probably want numbers 8 to 11 to look in `array[2]`, etc. If that's the case you can simplify it and remove the switch statement by using the `/` (divides by) and `%` (remainder) operators: `array[random_index/4][random_index%4] = random_number;`

Comment: Erwin is correct, however learning how to use the java debugger is a skill you can use to solve this problem and countless future problems too.

Comment: Absolutely learn how to use a debugger; it's an indispensable skill for a software engineer.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Thank you for your perfect comment!!! I fix them, then it correctly execute!!

Comment: @Bohemian Thank you for your advices!! I'll learn about debugger and use them!!

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).